# Kivy buttons not pressable

Tags: python, kivy

I dynamically created buttons based on how many sound files there are in a folder but I'm having an issue where I cannot press any of the buttons. I tried looking up tutorial or similar question but it seems as what I have should be correct, yet when I run it I get a window with buttons, but the buttons do nothing when pressed.

```
import os, glob

from os.path import isfile, join
from os import listdir
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.app import App

Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', False)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '500')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '300')

class Soundboard(GridLayout):
def soundSearch(self):
    os.chdir("./sound")
    self.sounds = []
    for Wav in glob.glob("*.wav"):
        self.sounds.append(Wav)
    for Flac in glob.glob("*.flac"):
        self.sounds.append(Flac)
    for mp3 in glob.glob("*.mp3"):
        self.sounds.append(mp3)

def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(Soundboard, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.soundSearch()
    self.cols = 3
    for sound in self.sounds:
        self.button = Button(text=os.path.splitext(sound)[0])
        self.button.bind(on_press=lambda x:self.clk())
        self.add_widget(self.button)
    self.row_force_default = True
    self.row_default_height = 40
    self.padding = [50, 10]
    self.spacing = 5

def clk(self, *args):
    print('The button is pushed')
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Soundboard()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided there is a problem with indentation. Other than that, the code works fine for me:

```
import glob
import os

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', False)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '500')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '300')

class Soundboard(GridLayout):
    def soundSearch(self):
        self.sounds = []
        os.chdir("./sound")
        for Wav in glob.glob("*.wav"):
            self.sounds.append(Wav)
        for Flac in glob.glob("*.flac"):
            self.sounds.append(Flac)
        for mp3 in glob.glob("*.mp3"):
            self.sounds.append(mp3)

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Soundboard, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.soundSearch()
        self.cols = 3
        for sound in self.sounds:
            self.button = Button(text=os.path.splitext(sound)[0])
            self.button.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.clk())
            self.add_widget(self.button)
        self.row_force_default = True
        self.row_default_height = 40
        self.padding = [50, 10]
        self.spacing = 5

    def clk(self, *args):
        print('The button is pushed')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Soundboard()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image: Works as expected]

Comment: I fixed the indentation but it still wont do anything when the button is pushed

Comment: What version of Python and kivy are you using? Did you run this exact code or something else with it? Do you have a .kv file associated with this code?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7, Kivy 1.9.1, and I do not have a .kv file associated with this code, i am running this from atom using something called Script

Comment: That's strange. Try running an empty app with just a single button. Does it work? If it works, then try removing code in your application until your button does something, maybe you will find the problem. You can also try updating kivy to 1.10 (and python to 3, of course)